# Only two monitor ports are detected on nVidia Quadro NVS 450

Tags: nvidia-quadro

I have an nVidia Quadro NVS 450 installed in a Dell Optiron 380.  Only DisplayPort #1 and DisplayPort #4 are detected by windows.  The machine has a BIOS setting to automatically choose the primary video card, or to disable the primary when a PCI-e card is installed (which it is).  Windows cannot see DisplayPort #2 and #3 no matter what I do.  I have tried the Windows Drivers, latest nVidia Drivers - no dice.

I am assured that this video card cannot break in this way.

I'm plum out of ideas.  I've tried reseating the video card.  I've contacted Dell and they've remoted in and looked around - threw their arms up after two hours.

Any ideas?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.  All four monitors are 1600x1200 Dell monitors.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I use a Nvidia NVS 450 and it seems to recognise only monitors #1 and #4. #2 and #3 show in NVIDIA Control Panel as "not connected".
CPU is hp X400 workstation Win7 Prof 64 bits

Comment: Ultimately, my problem was that the card was bad.  Swapped out the card and voila!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get a new Video Card.**

Ultimately, the video card was bad.  This was true even though our IT team and Dell both said that the graphic card could not break in this manner.

I think the key here is that even if I tried to use port #2 alone it still would not display.  Ports #2 and #3 were just dead no matter what I tried.  If #2 and #3 worked if I only used those two, then the other answer would have been best.

Comment: Absolutely bizarre failure, but I'm glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DisplayPort to DVI converters?  They need to be active adapters, or you can't run more than two simultaneously.  *This is true on 99% of hardware.*

If you're using active adapters (or native DisplayPort) then I have no clue.

Comment: Yes, I am using DisplayPort to DVI converters.  Then I'm plugging those into DVI cables to the monitor.  The converters are nVidia converters.

Comment: Would this cause the #2 and #3 ports to not even be detectable to Windows?

Comment: Yes, yes it would.  This is your problem.  EDIT: Try connecting ONLY to #2 or #3 and see what happens. ;)

Comment: When I connect ONLY to #2 or #3, the monitors are not recognized.  I don't even get a POST screen or anything.  If I switch it back to #1 after boot, it shows.

Comment: @Erick - Okay, that is slightly odd, but I don't have experience with this specific card.  It may be that they've tied the specific ports that are working to the TMDS signaling on that card (which would probably bring the cost down a bit, and doing the outermost ones makes sense from a cabling standpoint).  The real test would be trying actual DisplayPort on it, which should work unless the card itself is defective.  (That is, of course, always still a possibility - but you'll still never get more than 2 passive DVI adapters to work.)

Comment: Again, I have no hands-on experience with this card but I only know of ONE workstation card on the market right now (the FirePro 2460) that will work with more than 2 passive adapters over multiple DisplayPort outputs, and it requires the monitors to be exact matches in pairs or even it won't do it.  (There are probably some other really high-end workstation cards that support it though.)

Comment: I can say from experience that this configuration works.  As soon as we replaced the card, this worked perfectly.  I also have no idea that they are specifically "passive" adapters or not.  They just look like regular cables (although less than a foot long).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The card was installed on a Dell Optiplex 990 MT with a 250W PSU and only two of my LCDs were being detected. After much fiddling around, and evaluating the possibility of changing the power supply to a 450W, I was able to rectify the issue by using HDMI connectors instead of VGA. Apparently, the card encounters such problems converting digital into analog.

I would suggest using the provided converters with a DVI cable directly or a DVI - HDMI cable.

It has been smooth sailing for me since then and I didn't even have to change the power supply.

Comment: I was using the provided converters.

Answer (score -1):

Well I had the same issue and I got a second nv Quadro 450 and same issue was present then after about a couple minutes the system randomly detected the other monitors but it crashed the windows gui. After logging off and back on it appears to be working fine with 4 monitors. I'm using the supplied Display port to DVI adaptors. Had been running the original card for over a year with no issues. I am running a tyan s 4884 quad Opteron system with a 1200 watt PSU.the complete system is a audio recording console utilizing an RME PCI 9652 lightpipe audio card and the NV Quadro. So only using 1 of 2 pcie slots and 1 of 3 pcl slots. The mix desk automation, mouse/keyboard and the 88key midi controller are each on a separate USB port. There are 5  hard discs of 1tb each. All on the on board SATA controller and 64 gb of ram. This system replaced an otari 30 IPS 2" 24 track and a 24 track board in a heart beat and has been well more efficient and required allot less maintenance. I can record 24 tracks of audio and 64 tracks of midi in one pass. Screen real estate is my biggest asset. The old system was pretty much by ear and the automation was slow. I am going to see if now that one Quadro is working if I can repeat the steps with the second and get my projector and 48" flat screen running and see If I can start scoring films on this desk.