# nvidia quadro nvs 420 with three monitors

Tags: nvidia-quadro

I have a dell pc with an nvidia quadro nvs 420 video card.  I am currently running 2 monitors off the video card - a dell 24inch widescreen and a dell 19inch.  The 24inch connects directly through an hdmi cable.  the 19inch utilized a bizlink dvi to hdmi converter that allows it to plug into the dongle from the video card.  the bizlink connector also has a usb feed coming out of it that I connect into the pc.

I have a second 19inch that I would also like to use.  I have a dvi to hdmi connector, but it is just a straight cable connector, not a bizlink.  So I connect that to the video card and run a usb cable from the monitor to the pc.  I am able to utilize the usb ports from the monitor, but the display is not detected.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this working?  Do I have to use a bizlink connector?

Thanks for any thoughts.

EDIT - 
The exact cabling is as follows - 
there are two "dongles" coming out of the video card that each have 2 hdmi slots.
One has an hdmi cable that comes directly from the 24inch monitor and one empty slot.
The second has one slot connected to the bizlink connector.  The bizlink connector is connected via dvi cable to my monitor.  Also, coming from the bizlink connector to the pc is a usb connection.  this also has one empty slot.

I attempted to hook up the third monitor to either empty slot.  for this monitor, I have a dvi to hdmi cable.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There's nothing special about Bizlink, it's just a vendor...as far as your specific question, the Quadro NVS 420 is has only one VHDCI connector, so can you please be more specific about how you're cabling it?  What's going from the VHDCI to these other adapters?

Comment: I figured that, but is there something special about that connector that my straight cable connector doesn't have? Is there some kind of special connector that is needed to go from dvi to hdmi?

Comment: @czuroski - Edited my last comment as you were replying, because I realize I misread the model at first and needed more detail.  Please provide.

Comment: @Shinrai - I updated my original question.  thanks.

Comment: @czuroski - Hmm, this isn't standard cabling for this card (I've never seen it shipped with anything other than a breakout cable with 4x DVI ports, certainly never seen 4x HDMI).  I wonder if it's a Dell proprietary variant...I can't think that you'd need anything special, though, DVI and HDMI don't require active conversion so the cable should just work.  Are you sure the cable works at all?  Have you tried using it for the second monitor that's currently working?

Comment: I tried another dvi to hdmi cable/dongle, but it still isn't seeing it.

Comment: Do any other those work on the second monitor that current uses the Bizlink adapter if you swap it?  That's the operative question.  (If the answer is 'yes', then I have no clue what's wrong.)

Comment: I saw this post (http://superuser.com/questions/225342/only-two-monitor-ports-are-detected-on-nvidia-quadro-nvs-450/225348#225348) that said that you have to use active adapters to get more than 2 displays to work - could that be the problem?

Comment: @czuroski - That shouldn't be the case with this card, you never need active conversion between HDMI and DVI (unless it's like your BizLink connector which I assume has the USB to try and pass audio).  It's supposed to support 4 native DVI outputs - that's the point of the VHDCI connector.  Again, I wonder if this is a Dell-specific variant that's maybe crippled in some way...but then why do they provide a 4 headed cable?